# Moving on from accepting a counter offer

Tags: work-environment

I've very recently accepted a counter offer to stay in my current role. There are lots of articles online saying why I shouldn't accept one and seem to be based on US employment laws. I'm in the UK.

How can I quickly put this behind me, move on and show my employers I and they have made the right decision?

Answer (score 2):

Primarily by doing your job and doing it well.

Here is the tricky part: At some point you decided to leave and there was obviously a reason why you were unsatisfied with your current job. Whether or not you can move on really depends on that reason. In some cases it's really just money but typically there is more to it.  It would be best if the underlying reason has been clearly identified and a fix has been put in place that satisfies both parties.

So here is what my be going through your managers mind.

1. Wander is not the most loyal guy, I need to keep an eye on this
2. Apparently he cares a lot about money (if that's the actual reason), chances are he'll walk if the next good offer comes in
3. I'm really not sure whether Wander is a good candidate for long term development
4. The proper way to address his problems would have been to work through his management instead of going outside. Wander apparently doesn't trust me and is likely to go outside or behind my back again.

You can also have a talk with your manager about this: You can even start with listing the items above. "Hey boss, I'm glad I'm still working here and after the recent counter offer you are probably thinking <.....>". Then explain to him/her why he/she shouldn't be worried about this.

Comment: I think that's only one of a number of things that may be going through your manager's mind.